# Firefox: Communicator presence issue

Tags: office-communicator

We are using NameCtrl in our application and works fine in IE. But the same is not working in Firefox. The firefox website says that they doesnt support ActiveX controls. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/ActiveX

Is there a way to show communicator presence in Firefox too?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but this IS possible using browsers other than IE.

```
if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl");
} else {
    try {
        nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl");
    } catch (e){
        nameCtrl = (function(b){
            var c = null;
            try {
                c = document.getElementById(b);
                if (!Boolean(c) && (Boolean(navigator.mimeTypes) && navigator.mimeTypes[b] && navigator.mimeTypes[b].enabledPlugin)) {
                    var a = document.createElement("object");
                    a.id = b;
                    a.type = b;
                    a.width = "0";
                    a.height = "0";
                    a.style.setProperty("visibility", "hidden", "");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    c = document.getElementById(b)
                }
            } catch (d) {
                c = null
            }
            return c
        })("application/x-sharepoint-uc");
    }
}

if(nameCtrl && nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled){
// code here
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034488/firefox-skips-past-some-lines-of-javascript

Comment: Which code should written in "if(nameCtrl && nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled){" function @Andrew McGivery

Answer (score 0):

The NameCrl is an ActiveX component so it will only work in Internet Explorer.

There is no way to do this without custom development.  I would suggest using the UCMA APis, building a service that queries presence, and building a JavaScript API to call this service.